# Check if active java version is open-jdk or oracle

Tags: java, openjdk

`java -version` simply outputs :

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Need to find out if I am using the oracle version or the open-jdk version.

Comment: `openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)`
This is my java -version with openjdk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple bash script to check this out:

- Open any text editor (preferrably vim or emacs).
- create a file named script.sh (or any name with the .sh extension).
- paste the following code in it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  if [[ $(java -version 2>&1) == *"OpenJDK"* ]]; then echo ok; else echo 'not ok'; fi
  ```
- save and exit the editor.
- Execute the code using `bash name.sh` (The code return ok if you have a openJDK else not ok).

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain what your 1-line command does to make your answer more helpful to people who may not understand Bash.

Answer (score 0):

A typical output from running the same command to check the version for an OpenJDK version would be:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

[Sumit Kumar](https://askubuntu.com/users/579853/sumit-kumar) is just checking for this using `bash`